# Hive sub-query under FROM clause is throwing error

Tags: hive, hiveql

See below query:

```
SELECT session_date, 'min' as stats, mini as value, product, endpoint
from 
(select 
distinct TO_DATE(joinstart_ev_timestamp) as session_date, 
percentile_approx(cast(join_time as double),0.02) over (partition by 
TO_DATE(joinstart_ev_timestamp))/1000 as mini,
percentile_approx(cast(join_time as double),0.25) over (partition by 
TO_DATE(joinstart_ev_timestamp))/1000 as first_quartile,
percentile_approx(cast(join_time as double),0.50) over (partition by 
TO_DATE(joinstart_ev_timestamp))/1000 as jt,
percentile_approx(cast(join_time as double),0.75) over (partition by 
TO_DATE(joinstart_ev_timestamp))/1000 as third_quartile,
percentile_approx(cast(join_time as double),0.98) over (partition by 
TO_DATE(joinstart_ev_timestamp))/1000 as maxi,
product_name as product,
endpoint as endpoint
from datawarehouse.join_session_fact 
where  
TO_DATE(joinstart_ev_timestamp)  between 
date_add(TO_DATE(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp())),-16) and  
date_add(TO_DATE(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp())),-1)
and lower(product_name) LIKE 'gotowebinar%' 
and join_time>0 and join_time <= 600000 and join_time is not null 
and audio_connect_time >= 0  
and (entrypoint_access_time >= 0 or entrypoint_access_time is null)
and (panel_connect_time >= 0  or panel_connect_time is null) and version = 
'V2' and cast( concat( substr(data_input_date,1,4),'-' 
,substr(data_input_date,5,2),'-',substr(data_input_date,7,2) ) as date) 
between date_add(current_date(),-16) and  date_add(current_date(),-1))
```

Here, the sub-query is working fine. But when I am executing full query in Hive then I am getting below error:

```
Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 19:271 cannot recognize input near '<EOF>' '<EOF>' '<EOF>' in subquery source
```

I am not getting why this error is showing up? (Brackets looks fine to me)

Comment: Do you run it via cli - command line? or via file? (hive -f file.hql)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem on this subquery.  It needs a table alias in the end.  Since a subquery in a way is also a temp table, you need to name it.

For example, put an alias 't' at the end of your query and it will work.

```
SELECT session_date, 'min' as stats, mini as value, product, endpoint
from 
(select 
distinct TO_DATE(joinstart_ev_timestamp) as session_date,
..and so on..
between date_add(current_date(),-16) and  date_add(current_date(),-1)) t;
```